# AsNoTracking() in entityframework

Tags: entity-framework

I use `AsNoTracking()` and know that the first-level caching is disabled when using it. But how can using `AsNoTracking()` improve the performance? What is the benefit of using it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`AsNoTracking()` means that the entities will not be cached locally by the ObjectContext instance. This has a few practical benefits:

1. **Memory Usage**: Since the ObjectContext isn't referencing the entities after they're returned to you, the Garbage Collector can get rid of them as soon as you're no longer referencing them. Normally, the ObjectContext would need to be disposed before this could happen.
2. **Performance**: Since EF doesn't have to try to match every record returned from the database with a local entity in the identity map, your queries might execute slightly faster.
3. **Currency**: Since queries return entities materialized directly from the database results and do not rely on a local cache, the returned entities should always reflect the latest values in the database.
4. **Statelessness**: Since the entities are not being tracked by ObjectContext, you can continue to use the same ObjectContext instance indefinitely for read-only queries and need not feel constrained by the normal advice regarding having short-lived ObjectContexts.

`AsNoTracking()` is a good idea if you're only querying entities. It won't work if you need to update them, that is the tradeoff.

Comment: No caching / AsNoTracking() can make it slower. From the docs: "If you are repeatedly querying for the same entities on the same context, you might actually see a performance benefit from enabling change tracking."

Comment: Your last paragraph is missing some extra information. If you just get that data once its OK, but if you have a complex page and use the Entity to do allot of other things that is going to cause allot of SQL execution. You need to specify, `if you're only querying entities **once**.`