# Entity Framework and maintaining two instances of entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am very new to Entity Framework. In my application, I have first created an entity and got it saved in the database. Next, I have made some changes to the in-memory entity but before I saving the current changes to the database, I want to compare the values with what I have saved previously in the database.

When I am trying to load the entity from the database, EF in turn returns the entity which is currently in memory.

I am interested in knowing, how can I fetch an entity from database and also keep it separate from the current in-memory modified entity?

Sample Code

```
// new entity being created
Person p1 = GetPersonEntity();
p1.Age = 20;
Guid p1Id = _personRepository.AddOrUpdate(p1);

// An update but before saving I want to compare the new age with what was saved previously
p1.Age = 25;
Guid tempId = _personRepository.AddOrUpdate(p1);

// For comparison when I try to fetch entity from database, 
// I am getting the current in memory modified entity
_personRepository.FindBy(x => x.Id == p1Id).FirstOrDefault(); // doesn't return values from database
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load the object from the database if the object is still connected to the context (you haven't disposed of the context).

Check out [ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155228.aspx). The object that returns is an [ObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That object has both `OriginalValues`, and `CurrentValues` properties.

The DbContext maintains the state of the object from when it was originally loaded. This is what EF uses to determine if it needs to write to the database when you call `context.SaveChanges()`. You can access just the properties that have changed, if that's what you're looking for. Those are found in the `GetModifiedProperties()` method on the `ObjectStateEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [`AsNoTracking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which will return a query with tracking disabled...

```
return (from a in context.Animals.AsNoTracking()
        select a);
```

Comment: I tried adding AsNoTracking() but as mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527721/asnotracking-in-entityframework, it doesn't work when we have to update the entity as well.

Comment: You can still use these objects, you just need to understand how to re-attach them to the context.  You need to do a better job asking your question.