# C# Entity Framework Dynamic Proxy - Maintain Separate Object Instances of Same Record and Only Track Changes in One?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Long story short, I have some complicated objects (made up of tons of sub-objects [some generated by database first to EF objects], collections, and properties) that I use, and during an edit operation, I want to compare separate object instance values manually or reuse parts of my object with values from the database and other values from say an excel spreadsheet upload.  The problem is that entity framework appears to be referencing the same dynamic proxy between two separate object instances?

For example:

```
Car myCarOld = dbContext.Cars.Where(c=>c.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
Car myCar = dbContext.Cars.Where(c=>c.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
string oldMake = myCarOld.Make;
myCar.Make = "Toyota"; // Why is this line also updating myCarOld?  Shouldn't they be separate object instances with their own unique values?

if(myCarOld.Make != myCar.Make){
   Console.WriteLine("Hey, they don't match which is what I expect.");
}else{
   Console.WriteLine("Hey, they do match in value, huh?");
}
```

Outputs "Hey, they do match in value, huh?".  How do I prevent this from happening?  I want to track changes in the `myCar` object only without messing up the old original values in `myCarOld`.  I could deep clone the object before making changes to the object, but that doesn't work in my case because some of the base MVC objects I use like `SelectListItem` aren't serializable.

I read something about detaching the context object `context.Entry(personEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;`, but that seems like a lot of work to do it for all the EF objects in my custom object?  I'm not even sure that would help in my case, and I'm not sure if I'm describing what I'm looking to do properly either.  I'm confused.  Please help clear this up. I appreciate any help.

Similar to [Entity Framework and maintaining two instances of entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047810/entity-framework-and-maintaining-two-instances-of-entity) but is there a way to do it without altering the query?  I just want to take the result and keep it as a separate object with its own set of unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some complicated objects...

&

> I could deep clone the object before making changes to the object, but that doesn't work in my case because some of the base MVC objects I use like SelectListItem aren't serializable.

Short answer is stuff like `SelectListItem` don't belong mixed into entity graphs. Provided the entity relatives are eager loaded, a deep copy serialization would have been a good bet for tracking an initial state for a record.

What you are seeing is by design. It's no different if I have a collection of cars such as List cars, then go:

```
var car1 = cars[0];
var car2 = cars[0];
```

,,these point to the same car. EF will check to see if it knows about car ID "n", if not, it will load it from the DB and return it. From that point it knows about it, so if you ask for "n" again, it will return a reference to the same record.

Barring a deep copy clone, use separate DbContext instances:

```
using (var context = new CarContext())
{
  using (var originalContext = new CarContext())
  {
    var originalCar = originalContext.Cars.Single(x => x.CarId == carId);
    var car = context.Cars.Single(x => x.CarId == carId);

    // Do your thing to Car, reference originalCar for comparisons.

    context.SaveChanges();
    // Do not call originalContext.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

The cost is 2x reads from the database for your objects. Also, you cannot copy references from originalCar into car. I.e. anything like `car.Engine = originalCar.Engine`. The entity loaded by originalContext is tracked by originalContext, not context. Attempting to do so will result in errors regarding that the entity is already tracked. Attempting to detach and re-attach will also result in errors or wonky behaviour such as duplicate rows or key violations.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!  I ended up doing just this.